# Graham Scan Algorithm in Haskell

Tags: beginner, haskell, computational-geometry

I have just begun learning functional programming and Haskell.

This is my attempt to implement a solution to Graham Scan Algorithm in Haskell. Note that I am not even sure if this is indeed Graham Scan Algorithm, since I implemented this solution with only a few hints of the actual Graham Scan Algorithm. But I believe it to be correct and to have a \$\mathcal O\left(n \log(n)\right)\$ time complexity. However, I am still not quite there yet when it comes to understanding Lazy Evaluation, so not sure if it is indeed \$\mathcal O\left(n \log(n)\right)\$.

```
data Direction = LeftTurn | RightTurn | Straight deriving (Show, Eq)

findDirBetter (x, y) (x1, y1) (x2, y2) 
    | cros_product == 0 = Straight
    | cros_product > 0  = LeftTurn
    | cros_product < 0  = RightTurn
   where cros_product = (x1 - x) * (y2 - y1) - (y1 - y) * (x2 - x1)  

convex_hull_find []           = []
convex_hull_find (x:[])       = x:[]
convex_hull_find (x:x1:[])    = x:x1:[]
convex_hull_find (x:x1:x2:[]) = x:x1:x2:[]
convex_hull_find a            = (find_half_hull (tail sorted_x) [head sorted_x]) ++ (find_half_hull (tail (reverse sorted_x)) [head (reverse sorted_x)])
        where sorted_x                    = sortBy predicate a
              predicate (x, y) (x1, y1)   = compare x x1   
              find_half_hull ([]) hull    = tail hull
              find_half_hull l (x:[])     = find_half_hull (tail l) ((head l):x:[])
              find_half_hull l hull       = if findDirBetter (head (tail hull)) (head hull) (head l) /= RightTurn
                                            then find_half_hull (tail l) ((head l):hull)
                                            else find_half_hull l (tail hull)
```

Please critique everything from the algorithm to the code.

1. Is this Graham Scan Algorithm?
2. Is it \$\mathcal O\left(n \log(n)\right)\$?
3. Is this elegant, readable Haskell code?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Please keep in mind that we expect your code to work *as you intended*.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this Graham Scan Algorithm? Is it O(n log n)?

Yes, it is.

> Is this elegant, readable Haskell code?

No. It's buggy and far from elegant. Let's start with the bugs in `convex_hull_find`:

```
          convex_hull_find []           = []
          convex_hull_find (x:[])       = x:[]
Bug 1:    convex_hull_find (x:x1:[])    = x:x1:[]
Bug 2:    convex_hull_find (x:x1:x2:[]) = x:x1:x2:[]
          convex_hull_find a            = (find_half_hull (tail sorted_x) [head sorted_x]) ++ (find_half_hull (tail (reverse sorted_x)) [head (reverse sorted_x)])
Bug 3:      where sorted_x                    = sortBy predicate a
                  predicate (x, y) (x1, y1)   = compare x x1   
                  find_half_hull ([]) hull    = ...
```

The first bug is simple and obvious: for non-unique inputs like `[(0,0),(0,0)]`, the convex hull should be `[(0,0)]`, but the input is returned verbatim. Non-unique inputs of arbitrary length are also handled improperly. The second bug arises from reordering inputs of length three. Obviously, `[p1, p2, p3]` (counterclockwise triangle), `[p3, p2, p1]` (clockwise) and `[p2, p3, p1]` (different starting point) should all result in the exact same convex hull, namely the counterclockwise triangle `[p1, p2, p3]` that starts with the lowest-sorting point.

To fix the first bug, just ensure the input is sorted and unique before you do any processing, even in case of short-circuit evaluation. The second bug can be fixed by removing the special case for inputs of length three, there is no need for it anyway. Also, replace `head` and `tail` by `last` and `init` so the lowest-sorting point stays in the first position for arbitrary-length inputs.

The third bug is a bit more tricky: if two points have the same `x`-coordinate, sorting by `x` is insufficient to find the starting point. You need to brake ties by `y`. Luckily, that's how Haskell orders tuples by default, so just replace `sortBy predicate a` by `sort a`. The input `[(1,1),(1,0),(2,0),(1,2),(0,0)]` triggers the faulty behavior.

Below is a corrected version of the function, complete with type annotations and a docstring. I renamed `find_half_hull` to `grahamScan` and made it a first-order citizen to improve readability. Note that function names in Haskell are `camelCase` by convention, not `snake_case`.

```
convexHull :: (Num a, Ord a) => [(a,a)] -> [(a,a)]
-- ^ Convex hull in two dimensions.
convexHull points
  | length sorted <= 2 = sorted
  | otherwise = init (grahamScan sorted) ++ init (grahamScan $ reverse sorted)
  where sorted = map head $ group $ sort points
```

In addition to renaming `find_half_hull` to `grahamScan`, I split it in two separate, simple functions and slapped a docstring to each. They are defined as follows:

```
grahamScan :: (Num a, Ord a) => [(a,a)] -> [(a,a)]
-- ^ Performs a Graham scan on an ordered list of unique points.
grahamScan = foldr push []
  where push point stack = grahamEliminate (point:stack)
```

The first of those, `grahamScan`, simply pushes points onto a stack one by one (starting with the last) and calls `grahamEliminate` on each iteration. The latter tests if the top three point form a counterclockwise triangle and removes points as appropriate.

```
grahamEliminate :: (Num a, Ord a) => [(a,a)] -> [(a,a)]
-- ^ Pops second-to-top element from a stack if top three elements do
--   not form a counterclockwise triangle. Repeats if necessary.
grahamEliminate (p1:p2:p3:stack)
  | doubleArea p1 p2 p3 <= 0 = grahamEliminate (p1:p3:stack)
grahamEliminate stack = stack
```

Finally, the following code can be replaced by a one-liner. Just leave it to the caller to test the sign, it's easier than to test for your custom type.

```
data Direction = LeftTurn | RightTurn | Straight deriving (Show, Eq)

findDirBetter (x, y) (x1, y1) (x2, y2) 
    | cros_product == 0 = Straight
    | cros_product > 0  = LeftTurn
    | cros_product < 0  = RightTurn
    where cros_product = (x1 - x) * (y2 - y1) - (y1 - y) * (x2 - x1)
```

The complete code is then:

```
import Data.List


convexHull :: (Num a, Ord a) => [(a,a)] -> [(a,a)]
-- ^ Convex hull in two dimensions.
convexHull points
  | length sorted <= 2 = sorted
  | otherwise = init (grahamScan sorted) ++ init (grahamScan $ reverse sorted)
  where sorted = map head $ group $ sort points


grahamScan :: (Num a, Ord a) => [(a,a)] -> [(a,a)]
-- ^ Performs a Graham scan on an ordered list of unique points.
grahamScan = foldr push []
  where push point stack = grahamEliminate (point:stack)


grahamEliminate :: (Num a, Ord a) => [(a,a)] -> [(a,a)]
-- ^ Pops second-to-top element from a stack if top three elements do
--   not form a counterclockwise triangle. Repeats if necessary.
grahamEliminate (p1:p2:p3:stack)
  | doubleArea p1 p2 p3 <= 0 = grahamEliminate (p1:p3:stack)
grahamEliminate stack = stack


doubleArea :: Num a => (a,a) -> (a,a) -> (a,a) -> a
-- ^ Twice the area of a counterclockwise triangle. Negative if clockwise.
doubleArea (x1,y1) (x2,y2) (x3,y3) = (x2-x1) * (y3-y1) - (y2-y1) * (x3-x1)
```

Comment: Huh. You don't see post-documentation very often. Most code (especially in the standard library) uses pre-documentation, i.e. `-- |`, in order to keep function signature close to the body. But that's a matter of preference, I guess. Either way: your last doc string uses `-- |` instead of `-- ^`.